# CloudSQL read replica - can't execute stop slave, skip commands

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

My replication stuck at some `Last_SQL_Error` and  `Slave_SQL_Running: No`

Now i want to execute:

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1; 
START SLAVE;
```

but i can’t:

- Can’t stop slave:

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'someuser'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

- and can’t skip:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.
```

The user was created via the Google Cloud Platform -> SQL -> Chose Read Replica instance -> Users -> Create user account.

There it said: `Users created by using the Cloud Console have the same privileges as the root user.`

but still it doesn’t have the SUPER privileges (than i saw this in the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/faq#rr_listing))

```
Cloud SQL does not support SUPER privileges, which means that GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES statements will not work. As an alternative, you can use GRANT ALL ON `%`.*.
```

but it doesn’t work:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON `%`.* TO 'someuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

---

So How can I make the replication work again?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no [SUPER privilege for the root user on GCP SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#root-user), you can’t use stop slave command since it requires it. You can always stop the replication by using “DISABLE REPLICATION” on the [GCP UI](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/manage-replicas#disabling_replication).

If the replication stops (or gets stuck) in the process, you open an issue on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0) and we might be able to look into it from our side.

Comment: issue created: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145854146
Thank you.